# How to get value of deselected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Suppose I have a select like this:

```
<select id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="1">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="2">Lamborghini</option>
</select>
```

Imagine now that both values are selected, I deselect `Ferrari`, how can I retrieve the value of the deselected option, so in this case `Ferrari`?

I tried with:

```
$('#cars option').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

but the event is never fired, I also tried with `change`, this is fired, but I get only the selected values not the deselected one.

Comment: are you looking for something like: http://jsfiddle.net/o35wy4ex/ ?

Comment: @SandeepModak interesting solution, but what about if the deselected value is not the previous?

Comment: @sfarzoso please provide more information because you post question about multiple select and interesting solution is single select ...

Comment: @daremachine essentially I would like to know the value of deselcted option, in my example is `Ferrari`. Now if I have multiple values selected, the `change` event will return as val `[1, 2]`, so the solution proposed by sandeep will not works 'cause if there are a lot of values and I deselect a value which is not the previous, then the code will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could incorporate the usage of a class to track on change which elements are selected, and inversely which ones are no longer selected.

```js
var $cars = $('#cars').on('change', function(){
  // find the options that were selected, but are not now
  var $deselected = $cars.find('option.selected:not(:checked)');
  
  // add the selected class to the selected options for tracking
  $cars.find('option:checked').addClass('selected');
  // remove the selected class to untrack them
  $deselected.removeClass('selected');
  
  // report which options were deselected
  console.log($deselected.get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="1">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="2">Lamborghini</option>
</select>
```